# Multiple charts from single Google Sheet won't display

Tags: javascript, charts, google-sheets, google-visualization, visualization

I'm building a dashboard with Google Analytics data using the charts library and a Google Spreadsheet as my data source. I've set up a function for each chart, each with its own query to the sheet. Individually, everything works. When I run them together, I intermittently get just the second chart or a data error `Pie chart should have a first column of type string`.

I've seen a couple of answers that hint at this question, but nothing that's helped solve the problem.

Here's the javascript I have so far to draw both charts:

```
// Load Charts and the corechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});

// Draw the line chart for Reach when Charts is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawcpReach);

// Draw the pie chart for the UserType when Charts is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawcpUserType);

// Callback that draws the line chart for Reach.
function drawcpReach() {

  // Create the data table for Reach.
  var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B, C, D');
  var sheetName = 'cp_data'
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wH9Z3hA4iwRLC5IA6z4G3EKucSmW5lvGfiAkKLDDme0/gviz/tq?sheet=' + sheetName + '&headers=1&tq=' + queryString);
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();

  // Set options for Reach.
  var options = {
    height: 450,
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    colors: ['#68b3c8', '#eb5e28', '#f3bb45']
  };

  // Instantiate and draw the line chart for Reach.
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('cp-reach'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

// Callback that draws the pie chart for UserType.
function drawcpUserType() {

  // Create the data table for UserType.
  var sheetName = 'cp_data'
  var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wH9Z3hA4iwRLC5IA6z4G3EKucSmW5lvGfiAkKLDDme0/gviz/tq?sheet=' + sheetName + '&headers=1&range=E1:F3');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();

  // Set options for UserType.
  var options = {
    height: 450,
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    colors: ['#68b3c8', '#eb5e28']
  };

  // Instantiate and draw the chart for UserType.
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('user-type'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

I've also got a [fiddle set up](https://jsfiddle.net/mneznanski/avw1eg68/) that I'm working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just had a couple *'syntax'* errors...

**1. The charts couldn't find their containers**
need to use `id` attribute vs. `class`
`<div id="cp-reach"></div>`
vs.
`<div class="cp-reach"></div>`

**2. Can't have two *callback* functions with the same name, in the same scope**
renamed one of the `handleQueryResponse` to `handleQueryResponse2`

**3. (minor issue)** `var gid` was missing a semi-colon
`var gid = '333437552';`

otherwise, see working example...

```js
// Load Charts and the corechart package.
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawcpReach();
    drawcpUserType();
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});

// Callback that draws the line chart for Reach.
function drawcpReach() {
  // Create the data table for Reach.
  var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B, C, D');
  var gid = '333437552';
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wH9Z3hA4iwRLC5IA6z4G3EKucSmW5lvGfiAkKLDDme0/gviz/tq?gid=' + gid +
    '&headers=1&tq=' +
    queryString
  );
  query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();

  // Set options for Reach.
  var options = {
    height:450,
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    colors: ['#68b3c8', '#eb5e28', '#f3bb45']
  };

  // Instantiate and draw the line chart for Reach.
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('cp-reach'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

// Callback that draws the pie chart for UserType.
function drawcpUserType() {
  // Create the data table for UserType.
  var gid = '825312987';
  var query = new google.visualization.Query(
    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wH9Z3hA4iwRLC5IA6z4G3EKucSmW5lvGfiAkKLDDme0/gviz/tq?gid=' + gid +
    '&headers=1&range=A15:B17');
  query.send(handleQueryResponse2);
}

function handleQueryResponse2(response) {
  if (response.isError()) {
    alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
    return;
  }

  var data = response.getDataTable();

  // Set options for UserType.
  var options = {
    height: 450,
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    colors: ['#68b3c8', '#eb5e28']
  };

  // Instantiate and draw the chart for UserType.
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('user-type'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="cp-reach"></div>
<div id="user-type"></div>
```

Comment: hope this helps, as a side note, I typically only call `setOnLoadCallback` once per page, you can also include it in the `google.charts.load` statement, as in this example...